# How to use Wait For Function Properly

Tags: python, discord

I am having trouble on how to use the wait_for function properly. Here is the following code:

```
@client.command()
async def create(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.message.channel.send('Please name your character.')
    msg1 = await client.wait_for('ctx.message', check=None)
    await ctx.message.channel.send("Your name is {.content}.".format(msg1))
```

I am trying to have the Discord bot output the answer 'Your name "Blank."' When I do this with On_message, I can get this piece of code to work properly. However, it does not work when I try to create a command such as in this case "create." In fact after some testing, the function raises no errors or give any reason why it will not await for a response from the user. Clearly, my understanding of how to use the wait_for function is wrong. Any help in understanding how to use it or the proper way to get the output would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

To be more specific:

> event (str) – The event name, similar to the event reference, but
>   without the on_ prefix, to wait for.

So it should be `await client.wait_for('message', check=None)`

Also, you can add a check for the specific author like that: `check=lambda m: m.author == user`